# ValueError: index can't contain negative values

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm trying to preprocess audio files for speech emotion recognition, but I get an error about negative values.

Main code link(the preprocess part):
https://github.com/MeidanGR/SpeechEmotionRecognition_Realtime/blob/main/2_model.ipynb

```
import time
tic = time.perf_counter()

# Initialize data lists
rms = []
zcr = []
mfcc = []
emotions = []

# Initialize variables
total_length = 173056 # desired frame length for all of the audio samples.
frame_length = 2048
hop_length = 512

folder_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/AudioFiles' 

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
  for file in files: 

    # Fetch the sample rate.
      _, sr = librosa.load(path = os.path.join(subdir,file), sr = None) # sr (the sample rate) is used for librosa's MFCCs. '_' is irrelevant.
    # Load the audio file.
      rawsound = AudioSegment.from_file(os.path.join(subdir,file)) 
    # Normalize the audio to +5.0 dBFS.
      normalizedsound = effects.normalize(rawsound, headroom = 0) 
    # Transform the normalized audio to np.array of samples.
      normal_x = np.array(normalizedsound.get_array_of_samples(), dtype = 'float32')
    # Trim silence from the beginning and the end.
      xt, index = librosa.effects.trim(normal_x, top_db=30)
      #print(file,"\t", len(xt), "\t", rawsound.dBFS, "\t", normalizedsound.dBFS) #--QA purposes if needed-- 
    # Pad for duration equalization.
      padded_x = np.pad(xt, (0, total_length-len(xt)), 'constant')
    # Noise reduction.
      final_x = nr.reduce_noise(padded_x, sr=sr) #updated 03/03/22
       
   # Features extraction 
      f1 = librosa.feature.rms(final_x, frame_length=frame_length, hop_length=hop_length) # Energy - Root Mean Square   
      f2 = librosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(final_x , frame_length=frame_length, hop_length=hop_length, center=True) # ZCR      
      f3 = librosa.feature.mfcc(final_x, sr=sr, n_mfcc=13, hop_length = hop_length) # MFCC
      
   # Emotion extraction from the different databases
      if (find_emotion_T(file) != "-1"): #TESS database validation
            name = find_emotion_T(file)
      else:                              #RAVDESS database validation
            name = file[6:8]                      

   # Filling the data lists  
      rms.append(f1)
      zcr.append(f2)
      mfcc.append(f3)
      emotions.append(emotionfix(name)) 

toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Running time: {(toc - tic)/60:0.4f} minutes")
```

[image: Error]

Comment: You can paste a code sample, highlight it, and press the `{}` button to make it a code block. Since this is a simple markup language, its really just looking for text indented with 4 spaces to highlight as code.

Comment: I prefer the ``` method, far easier to work with imo.

Comment: According to the error, `total_length-len(xt)` is negative sometimes, and it can't be.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset has been updated since `MeidanGR` uploads the project. The dataset now contains more data than before thus it is going negative indexing as you are using
`total_length = 173056 # desired frame length for all of the audio samples.` which is a fixed value.

The total length is now for each dataset is `243200`

Therefore using the following value will solve your problem.

```
total_length = 243200*2
```

I'm assuming you are using both the dataset, `RAVDESS` and `TESS`